# More userfriendly interface to (scipy.)optimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

when using scipy.optimize, but also when using pyopt, the optimization function must be of the form:

```
def obj(x):
```

Usually the next lines will then be something like:

```
wingspan   =x[0]
AspectRatio=x[1]
```

Equally, for the constraints, we must use un-intuitive names:

```
{'type': 'eq',
...          'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[0]**3 - x[1]]),
...          'jac' : lambda x: np.array([3.0*(x[0]**2.0), -1.0])}
```

Or in pyopt:

```
opt_prob.addCon('x1', type='i', lower=-inf, upper=inf, equal=0.0)
```

Here, it is even worse (?): Here, the name is x1 and in the objective-function it becomes x[0].

Are there any helper-functions that change this very mathematic interface to a more 'engineering' interface?

Similarly: The constraints usually need to be normalized:
If I want weight<9000:

```
w=weight/9000-1
```

Also here, I wonder, if there is a more 'engineering' interface?
Ideally I would like:

```
def obj(span=40, aspect_ratio=12, aileron=0, dihedral=0):
   return compute_blockfuel(span, aspect_ratio, aileron, dihedral)

def weight(span=40, aspect_ratio=12):
   return span*span*aspect_ratio
```

and:

```
opt=optimize(obj, 'maximize')
opt.add_var(span, min=10, max=20)
opt.add_cons(weight, max=9000)
opt.start()
```

Does such a wrapper for scipy.optimize or pyopt exist? If not, is there a good reason? If not: How would I create such a wrapper?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Just wrap x to *whatever you like* (a function transforming a vector x) and use functions for the objective and constraints, which in the first line use that wrapper (as this x-vector is the core-concept of scipy.minimize). Depending on *whatever you do*, you also need to wrap this to a scalar or a vector (also core-concept). Nobody forces you to use lambdas / anonymous functions for constraints.